# Missing libGL.so.1 when trying to launch Steam

Tags: steam

I am new to Linux only this evening. I am trying to play Football Manager 2016 via my Chromebook 2 and have installed Ubuntu.

Unfortunately I am not able to launch Steam via the Software Center and I am being greeted with errors. If anybody with some knowledge could help me I would be eternally grateful.

When trying to install, this error comes up:

> You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: `libGL.so.1`

How can I fix this?

Comment: See if running this command in a terminal works: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`

Comment: We need all the details as well as full, *specific* errors. The entire thing. Please [edit] your question to include these details.

Comment: Sorry for the very poor explanation of my scenario there. I am extremely high and numb after experiencing coding for the first time in my life. They need to teach it in schools they really do!

Answer (score 2):

Running the following command will allow your computer to work with 32-bit libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

Run that in a terminal and try to install Steam again.

Comment: I needed sudo apt update first :)