# Ubuntu 16.4 , need i386 libGL.so.1 I think (but not for Steam)

Tags: 16.04, 32-bit

The error message looks like this:

/home/myusername/zyzzyva-3.1.0/bin/NASPAZyzzyva310: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This software (naspa-zyzzyva) is given to me pre-compiled without source code so I don't have the option of compiling it.  It's supposed to have a license to use some parts of it.

It sort of seems like I could find the library (libGL.so.1) in mesa somehow but I am not clear on what is going on. It seems the 32 bit libraries are organized differently in 16.4 vs. 14.x and 17.x, so some of the answers I find can not be applied.

Is there a way to make it be found automatically?  Or do I need to do apt-get mesa:i386 or what ...

Thanks :)

Comment: Never mind, I found it.  This answers it, even though it is for Steam!  https://askubuntu.com/questions/731426/missing-libgl-so-1-when-trying-to-launch-steam

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is making it work

[Missing libGL.so.1 when trying to launch Steam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731426/missing-libgl-so-1-when-trying-to-launch-steam)

This installs the 32-bit graphics libraries that are needed.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

Comment: Also note that if you wanna play games, 16.04 has an old software. There were lots of changes you'd like for performance both [in kernel](https://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxVersions) and [in Mesa](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/log/).